# Update field in mongoDB with it's substring

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to shorten all long descriptions in my object. 
I have searched and read many articles but I can't figure out how to do this simple task in mongoDB.
What I am trying to achieve would be simple in SQL:

```
UPDATE AssetDocument SET description = substr(description, 0, 500) WHERE length(description) > 500
```

Can please someone help me do this in MongoDB?

I have tried this:

```
db.AssetDocument.updateMany(
{$where: "this.metadata.description.length > 500"},
{$set: { "metadata.description": { $substr: ["metadata.description", 0, 500]}}});
```

This gives me errmsg: `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$substr' in 'metadata.description.$substr' is not valid for storage.`

Then I tried this:

```
db.AssetDocument.find({
  $where: "this.metadata.description.length > 500"
}).forEach(function(e){
  e.metadata.description = {$substr: [e.metadata.description, 0, 500]};
  db.AssetDocument.save(e);
});
```

But this doesn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.AssetDocument.find({
  $where: "this.description.length > 500"
}).forEach(function(e){
  e.description = e.description.substr(0,500);
  db.AssetDocument.save(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
db.AssetDocument.find({}).forEach(function(e)
{ if(e.description.length<500) 
e.metadata.description=  e.metadata.description.substr(0,500)
 db.AssetDocument.save(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**This is working**
db.getCollection("AssetDocument").find({
   $where: "this.description.length > 100"
}).forEach(function(e){
   description = e.description.substr(0, 100);
   db.getCollection("AssetDocument").updateOne({_id: e._id}, 
     {"$set": {"description": description}});
});
```